# Mongoose - how to replace _id as primary index?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, query-performance

Given the below example schema, is there a way to make the "email" the primary index on UserSchema instead of the default "_id" (assuming email is always unique)? 
If possible, would performance be better searching on "email" when it is the primary index?

Also, as an alternative, is it possible to do a primary index on a composit or a compound field If so, what would the syntax look like for a primary key on "firstName.firstName"? 
In this case, how would StorySchema reference UserSchema. Would the syntax look the same or different?

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const StorySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
mongoose.model('stories', StorySchema);

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  _id: false,
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String
  },
});
mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

Comment: One option is store the email ids in _id field.

Comment: I can't find any concept named `primary index`, do you mean `primary key`? there would be no performance ‍‍advantage between indexes until you're choosing them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The mongoose documentation may be helpful after all. I'm not sure what the 1 identifies. For example: {_id: 1 ..., { groupNumber: 1 ... lastname: 1 ... .

https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/index-unique/

Looks like an example of defining the primary key using one or more fields:

```
{ _id: 1, a: [ { loc: "A", qty: 5 }, { qty: 10 } ] }
```

Example of defining a compound secondary index.

```
db.members.createIndex( { groupNumber: 1, lastname: 1, firstname: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```